# Passing Julia value to MATLAB

Tags: matlab, julia

Suppose that I generate a random matrix A in Julia. For clarity suppose this random matrix is A=[1 2; 3 4].

Now I want to use the exact same matrix A=[1 2; 3 4] in MATLAB. So my question is how do I pass this Matrix A into MATLAB? I have seen MATLAB.jl, but this is more about calling functions, what I want to do should be much simpler. I just want to pass a value from Julia to MATLAB.

Comment: Haven't used Matlab, but "normally" (for the interface packages dealing with Python, R, C++,...) it is the interface package itself that, other than allowing to call functions in the foreign language, deals with type conversion of objects between the two languages, so have a better look at MATLAB.jl in your case

Comment: It seems like the easiest way will be to call Julia from MATLAB and not the other way around. However, I am not a big fan of this since that will "break" the MATLAB code.

Comment: You could use MATLAB.jl to serialize the object in MATLAB format and then load it in a Matlab session. Or simply save that to a delimited file and than load from Matlab. If you need to be interactive you need to use aforementioned Matlab.jl or you could make some RESTfl service using Genie.jl and call this from Matlab. Depending in your scenario there are plenty of integration patterns